# iOS - Objective C code to get App Version of 3rd party App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know in Android we have mechanism of identifying the version of 3rd party apps.

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);    
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {    
    System.out.println(packageInfo.versionName);    
}
```

Does any one know how I can find the same in iOS - Objective C

Thanks

Comment: You mean get some other app's version? I don't think there's a way, just because of privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking, there's no way to mimic the functionality of `PackageManager`  You can't list installed applications, much less, get specific information about them.